# Synchronise two timers in flash/html

Tags: html, flash

I am building a simple website with two countdown timers. The problem is that they do not synchronize. When the webpage loads, one timer is noticably ahead of the other. This is the html is used

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">

    #flashContent { width:100%; height:100%; }

    </style>
</head>

<body >

<div id="flashContent" align="center" >

        <object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="400" height="250" id="Timer" align="middle">
            <param name="movie" value="Timer.swf" />
            <param name="quality" value="high" />
            <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
            <param name="play" value="true" />
            <param name="loop" value="true" />
            <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
            <param name="scale" value="showall" />
            <param name="menu" value="true" />
            <param name="devicefont" value="false" />
            <param name="salign" value="" />
            <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
            <!--[if !IE]>-->
            <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="Timer.swf" width="400" height="250">
                <param name="movie" value="Timer.swf" />
                <param name="quality" value="high" />
                <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
                <param name="play" value="true" />
                <param name="loop" value="true" />
                <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
                <param name="scale" value="showall" />
                <param name="menu" value="true" />
                <param name="devicefont" value="false" />
                <param name="salign" value="" />
                <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
            <!--<![endif]-->
                <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash">
                    <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" />
                </a>
            <!--[if !IE]>-->
            </object>
            <!--<![endif]-->
        </object>

        <object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="400" height="250" id="Timer" align="middle">
            <param name="movie" value="Timer.swf" />
            <param name="quality" value="high" />
            <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
            <param name="play" value="true" />
            <param name="loop" value="true" />
            <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
            <param name="scale" value="showall" />
            <param name="menu" value="true" />
            <param name="devicefont" value="false" />
            <param name="salign" value="" />
            <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
            <!--[if !IE]>-->
            <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="Timer.swf" width="400" height="250">
                <param name="movie" value="Timer.swf" />
                <param name="quality" value="high" />
                <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
                <param name="play" value="true" />
                <param name="loop" value="true" />
                <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
                <param name="scale" value="showall" />
                <param name="menu" value="true" />
                <param name="devicefont" value="false" />
                <param name="salign" value="" />
                <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
            <!--<![endif]-->
                <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash">
                    <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" />
                </a>
            <!--[if !IE]>-->
            </object>
            <!--<![endif]-->
        </object>

        </div>

</body>
```

I used two layers in the flash vid. One with background elements (including the dynamic text for the timer), and one with only this piece of code:

stop();

var countDownTimer:Timer = new Timer(10);

countDownTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, updateTimer);

countDownTimer.start();

function updateTimer(Event:TimerEvent):void{

```
var today:Date = new Date();
var destination:Date = new Date(2012,10,9,18,0,0,0);

if(destination.getTime()-today.getTime() < 0 ){

    Time_txt.text = "00:00:00:00";
    Title_txt.text = "It's Double Time!";

}else{

var daysLeft = Math.floor((destination.getTime()-today.getTime())/(1000*60*60*24));
var hoursLeft = Math.floor(((destination.getTime()-today.getTime())/(1000*60*60))-daysLeft*24);
var minutesLeft = Math.floor(((destination.getTime()-today.getTime())/(1000*60))-daysLeft*24*60-hoursLeft*60);
var secondsLeft = Math.floor(((destination.getTime()-today.getTime())/(1000))-daysLeft*24*60*60-hoursLeft*60*60-minutesLeft*60);

var days:String = new String(daysLeft);
var hours:String = new String(hoursLeft);
var minutes:String = new String(minutesLeft);
var seconds:String = new String(secondsLeft);

if(days.length < 2) days = "0" + days;
if(hours.length < 2) hours = "0" + hours;
if(minutes.length < 2) minutes = "0" + minutes;
if(seconds.length < 2) seconds = "0" + seconds;

var time:String = days +":"+ hours+":"+minutes+":"+seconds;

Time_txt.text = time;
Title_txt.text = "Jazz awaits in...";
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

use LocalConnection (link below) to create a connection between the two files.  Run the timer in one... then in your updateTime() method, pass the timer text over the connection to the other swf.  Presto!

localConnection.send("myConnection", "updateMethodName", time);

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/LocalConnection.html

Comment: hey did this solve your problem?  Going through old questions to see how it went?